# How to access a file using java io inside a web app(Glassfish server)

Tags: java, servlets, properties, glassfish

I am trying to make a connection with database from a class called `ConnectionProvider`.
I call `ConnectionProvider.getConnection()` inside `Servlet`  which return `Connection` refrence.
But I get exception during execution of this class:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: db.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
```

code of ConnectionProvider:

```
    public class ConnectionProvider  {

static Properties prop;

static {
    try{
          prop= new Properties();
          prop.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
       }catch(Exception e){  
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection()  {

Connection con=null;
try{

Class.forName(prop.getProperty("driver"));
con=DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("url"),prop.getProperty("user"),prop.getProperty("pass"));
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}

return con;


}

}
```

I cannot use ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() bcause code is not called from servlet.
I have tried to put property file in each and every location inside public folder (root) of web app but that doesn't help.
I also donot want to hardcode the connectivity code inside Servlet and want some helper class to perform the connectivity code for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in the classpath and load it from the classpath. The below example assumes that you've dropped `db.properties` in the root of the classpath (e.g. the root of your package structure; in Eclipse for example that would be straight in the `src` folder):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
    properties.load(input);
} finally {
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, your code style of ignoring the exception and just printing its trace and then continuing the code flow is a very bad practice. Your code would return a `null` connection and the calling code would break with `NullPointerException`. You should really handle the exception in a sensible manner. In this particular case, just throw it or rethrow it in another exception.

Loading the driver class everytime in the `getConnection()` is also unnecessary. One time is enough during application's lifetime. You could do it in for example that `static` block. Don't forget to rethrow any caught exception as `ExceptionInInitializerError`.